# jQuery dotdotdot plugin function doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, dotdotdot

I added a plugin to jQuery today, which is [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/), but it does not work, I added two more plugins, too, all jQuery plugins I download don't work.
Here's my `<head>`:

```
<title><?php echo $title;?> | Powerity</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/dotdotdot.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
```

And what I typed in my `plugins.js` file is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("p").dotdotdot();
});
```

But the function `dotdotdot` doesn't seem to exist....\

Comment: Check your console. Most likely you have an error somewhere.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, no errors...

Comment: Check in the network tab of your developer console if the script was successfully loaded. Check in the console tab for errors.

Comment: @marekful Yep, it's loaded.

Comment: Also, note that you can do this in CSS alone: `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Comment: If there is no errors, then it's more likely that you have css problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know that, but my paragraph isn't a single line only, and this plugin's gonna save my life, but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Mehdi Does Bootstrap mess it up?

Comment: could you show some html code of your `<p>` or its surrounding wrapper `<div>`?

Comment: I checked that plugin, it seems there are some configuration options to be used. I doubt if you are missing the configuration part.

Comment: @Mehdi It's just a paragraph.. with no `div`

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary No, I'm not...

Comment: I tried it in an IDE, and... http://prntscr.com/7pewtq

Comment: It seems they like `<div>` with fixed height. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Mehdi The function doesn't even seem to work...

Comment: I know it sounds lame but try something like `<p style="display: block; height: 20px;">` instead of a simple `<p>`

Comment: Are you missing bootstrap.js? Try adding it after jQuery.js. I'm not sure, just give it a try :)

Comment: Take a look at [**this jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fo4z05qp/) and try replicating the steps (also look at CSS) in your own system.

Comment: the `dotdotdot` looks fine in this jsfiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/y1nn3e02/3/

Comment: @Mehdi Mhmmm, weird... The problem's on my side... and I think it's a setup problem, but I don't know what it is!

Comment: @Mehdi Did you see the screenshot I posted? my IDE says it doesn't exist.

Comment: @PepsiGam3r Yeah but you also said there is no error in console. You cannot trust IDE, but console should capture the error in that case. It is not the bootstrap problem either. I included bootstrap.min.css as an extra resource.